# How does the OS know what virtual page a specific memory address references?

Tags: c++, operating-system, heap-memory, cpu, virtual-memory

I am trying to understand how variables allocated in programs (such as with the *new* keyword in C++) translate to virtual pages.

My understanding is that each process will have its own virtual memory space and this space will be segmented into several pages of a fixed size (such as 64 bytes). When we allocate memory in our program, we start at the first address and move downwards. So if we allocated 128 bytes, we would be consuming two pages, both of which would be slotted into the MMU page table.

The part that I'm having difficulty in understanding is the following:

- If I dynamically allocated an integer in memory, I could potentially have a memory address that reads something like 0x78C75ABC
- How does the OS know what corresponding virtual page this memory address corresponds to?

I am assuming that it basically runs a count from 0 -> memory address and divides that by the fixed page size (64 bytes). Then it can access the page table with this number.

I understand that a large portion of this would be system-dependent but I'm just trying to grasp a general understanding of it.
Thanks!

Comment: Given your example values, with 64 byte pages the address 0x78C75ABC would be in page 0x78C75ABC / 64.

Comment: _"How does the OS know what corresponding virtual page this memory address corresponds to?"_ - The OS is responsible for maintaining the Page Table, while the MMU only has access to a subset of the Page Table (because the Page Table can often be too big to fit into the superfast registers that the MMU will be using, e.g. on a 32-bit system with 4KB pages it's 4MB (note that 4K-sized pages are the norm on desktop PCs).

Comment: *allocate an integer* ... and *How does the OS know what corresponding virtual page this memory address corresponds to?* - you have that backwards.  The OS had to pick a free page in virtual address space in the first place to map whatever physical page it picked.  (Or for a small allocation like an int or small struct, pick a partly-used page that had some free space).  If there isn't already a physical page backing that virtual page, it would have to allocate a free physical page (aka page frame) as well, with a separate allocator.

Comment: virt->phys mapping data structures (page tables) are indexed by virtual address, although it might need to allocate more physical pages for parts of the page table tree if they weren't already populated with "invalid" entries (page-table entry = PTE).  So the kernel knows where to put the physical address so the hardware page-walker will be able to find it upon TLB miss.

Comment: Computers use binary, and page sizes are powers of 2, so finding the address of the start of a page that contains the address is trivial, just a bitwise AND to clear the low `page_offset` bits of the address.  In this case, `page = ptr & -64;`  Or the virtual page number is just `ptr >> 6`.

Comment: There are two *very* different topics here. One is dynamic allocation and the other is virtual memory. They are largely orthogonal and best discussed separately.

Comment: With virtual memory 0x78C75ABC is basically a lookup for an address.  The OS and CPU work together to make sure the data ends up at some physical location when you need it and then gets translated into a physical address for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Around the 40 minute mark, [`*(char*)0 = 0;`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFIqNZ8VbRY) gets into the thick of this.  It's a bit of a slow start, but that's just part of the pacing to lure you down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Cordes pointed out in a comment, your question seems to have things kind of backwards.

Disclaimer: details can and do vary somewhat depending on the OS and hardware you're using. So what I'm going to describe is one possible scenario, not necessarily exactly how your particular OS works.

The OS starts out "owning" all the physical memory on the machine.

When your program needs some memory, it allocates it from the OS. To satisfy that request, the OS will allocate some address space (but not necessarily any physical memory) to satisfy the request. To do that, it creates page table entries for as many pages as necessary to satisfy the request.

Initially, it marks all those addresses as "valid", but also as "not present", meaning there's no physical memory to back them, so attempting to read or write any of those addresses will result in a processor exception.

Then when your program tries to read or write inside that block of memory, a processor exception will be raised. The exception handler will look at the page table entry, but there's no physical memory attached to it, so it'll allocate some physical memory to back that address. It'll modify the page table entry to map that virtual address to whatever physical memory page it allocated. Finally, it'll return from the exception, so the instruction can finish executing.

As far as how the mapping is done, you've described it reasonably accurately. The size of a page is normally a power of 2 (and usually quite a bit larger than 64 bytes--usually at least 4 kilobytes). Since the page size is a power of 2, we can easily break the virtual address into two pieces: the upper bits become the page number, and the lower bits (e.g., 12 least significant bits for a 4 kilobyte page size) are an offset into that page.

So, the page table is basically an array of physical addresses that's indexed by page numbers (with a few other bits of data added, such as accessibility--whether this page is read/write or read-only, for example). When you use a virtual address, the processor splits the address into the bottom N bits and the upper M bits. It uses the upper M bits to look up a physical address in the page table, then adds on the bottom N bits as an offset into the page to get a complete physical address.

Comment: Thank you Jerry, this was exactly the answer that I was looking for. I suspected that some sort of mapping must occur but I wanted to confirm this before I committed to that understanding. The extra detail was very much appreciated.

I have found that, while a lot of resources detail virtual memory singularly, not many of them explain how actual variables are involved in the process.